# Add Google Tracker Tag to Login Page

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to add a Google Analytics tracker tag to my login page (wp-login.php).

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to hook onto the `login_footer` action and output your GA code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'login_footer', 'zzMzz_output_ga' );

function zzMzz_output_ga() {
    ?>
<!--
Your Google analytics <script> tag here
-->
    <?php
}
```